# ruby regex, everything BUT what is in parentheses and brackets

Tags: ruby, regex

i am trying to write a regex that produces the content in a string that is NOT in parentheses or brackets. The parentheses is always a year, and the brackets could contain any normal characters, upper and lower case. i was going about it by finding the brackets and parentheses and then [^\regex] to escape it (is this right?)

here's the string:

```
s = 'Some words (1999) [THINGS]
```

and the regex:

```
/[^(\(\d{4}\))|\[.*\]]/
```

but this includes the characters inside the brackets see (http://rubular.com/r/bbpcnnGgCI)

everything works up until adding the [^\regex]

for example, this works to get (1999):

```
>> puts s.match(/\(\d{4}\)/)
(1999)
```

and for whats in brackets:

```
>> puts s.match(/\[.*\]/)
[THINGS]
```

but put them together using | for "or":

```
>> puts s.match(/\(\d{4}\)|\[.*\]/)
(1999)
```

...it just matches the parentheses and its contents.

what's going on here?

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this `/\(.+/` which will match everything from the opening `(` onwards. If you strip that out, you're left with `'Some words'` which should be what you need?

Two points

1. I may be misunderstanding the question
2. You need something more complicated if there's any possibility of an `(` appearing earlier in the string.

By the way, I find [this](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) rather valuable when trying to come up with Regex patterns.

**Edit** This pattern should only match stuff in brackets even if there is a stray bracket earlier in the string.

```
string.gsub(/(\(|\[).+(\)|\])/, '')
```

Comment: @duckyfizz perfect! and a great resource. it errored out with replace but worked great with gsub.

Comment: Sorry of course I meant gsub. Had replace in my head for some reason.

Comment: im going to have to work on this one a little, as i also have strings without parentheses or brackets, and when it runs on those strings, it wipes it out (nil). any ideas?

Comment: make sure you're using `gsub` and not `gsub!`. The one with the exclamation mark will return `nil` if no match is found but the one without will just return the origional string without complaining. Does that help? In Ruby, the `!` is generally used to signify that a method may change the original object or raise unwanted errors.

Comment: ah perfect! i knew ! would permanently change it, but i didnt realize without it the variable would not change (not return nil). thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`(\(\d{4}\))|\[.*\]` means "four digits surrounded in parentheses, and also captured in a group; or anything between square brackets".

`[^...]` **does not** mean "anything that isn't matched by `...`". `[]` sets up a character-set, which if it starts with `^` is negated. `[^(\(\d{4}\))|\[.*\]]` means "a character that is not an open parenthesis or an open parenthesis or a digit or an open brace or a 4 or a close brace or a close parenthesis or a close parenthesis or a pipe or an open square bracket or a period or a star or a close square bracket".

You want to match "any text that is not in parentheses or brackets". This is not easily expressed as a regex directly. What you really want to do is split the string using "any parenthesized or bracketed item" as a delimiter.

I don't know the ruby syntax, but in Python this looks like:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"(?:\[[^\]]*\])|(?:\(\d{4}*\))")

pattern.split('Some words (1999) [THINGS]') # ['Some words ', ' ', '']
```

That gives you the individual pieces, assuming you need them. If you're just going to join them up again, then the "replace the delimiters with empty strings" (i.e. `gsub`) approach works just fine.

Comment: i see what you are saying. since there is no explicit "match everything BUT this", instead split it up and then call the element of the array explicitly. makes perfect sense. thank you for breaking down the regex, i feel like as it gets longer i start to lose the meaning of what i am doing :)

Comment: You might find it helps to write functions that glue pieces of regexes together. For example (again in Python): `def regex_any(*x): return '(%s)' % '|'.join(x)`. Or use the /x regex flag.

Comment: im beginning to see the /x flag may help us new to regrex's. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about looking at this from the opposite direction: Try replacing the pattern `\(\d{4}\)` with blank `""`, then you'll have what you want:

```
s.gsub("\(\d{4}\)", "")
```

**EDITED:** To incorporate syntax correction suggested by @rick (thx @rick!)

Comment: like this? http://rubular.com/r/mFSfx2wIez that seems to give me everything but the actual parentheses and brackets, i dont want the contents of them either.

Comment: oh i see what you're saying. using gsub im getting the same result, nothing changed, but i see where youre going with this...    >> s.gsub("\(\d{4}\)", "")
=> "Artist name (1999) [FLAC]"

Comment: @rick: note that the brackets are escaped ie \(\d{4}\) - not (\d{4}) as in your comment

Comment: posting a comment on SO requires an additional level of backslash-escaping ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you need something that matches multiple sets of brackets in a string mixed with words this will work http://rubular.com/r/rvcO4TyBLq

```
((\(\d{4}\))|(\[[^\]]+\]))+
```